# Python: Find backslash in imported string

Tags: python, string, backslash

I'm trying to snip the first phrase in an imported string (s) which always takes the form:

`"\first phrase\\...\ ... "`

The first phrase can be any length and consist of more than one word

The code I initially tried was:

```
phrase = s[1:s.find('\',1,len(s))]
```

which obviously didn't work.

`r'\'` won't compile (returns EOL error).

Variations of the following:  `r'\\\'; r'\\\\\\\', "\\\", "\\\\\\\""`
resolve to: `phrase = s[1:-1]`.

As the first character is always a backslash I've also tried:

```
phrase = s[1:find(s[0:1],1,len(s))], but it wasn't having any of it.
```

Any suggestions appreciated, this was supposed to be a 10 minute job!

Comment: As a side note: `s.find(x, 1, len(s))` is unnecessary; you can just do `s.find(x, 1)`. But, as Prashant suggested, split is usually simpler and clearer. And neither one has anything to do with your problem.

Comment: Also, if you're testing this with `s="\first phrase\...\ ... "`, then the first character of s is a formfeed, not a backslash, which might explain why you're having so many problems.

Answer (score 7):

Backslashes in string literals need to be escaped.

```
'\\'
```

Comment: +1. If you change the OP's code by one character to escape the backslash, `phrase` ends up as 'first phrase', exactly as requested. (However, I suspect he may be having problems testing it because he's doing `s="\first phrase\...\ ..."`, which of course doesn't actually start with a backslash.)

Answer (score 5):

I just use the split command, which will handle your multi-word requirement easily:

```
>>> s='\\first phrase\\second phrase\\third phrase\\'
>>> print s
\first phrase\second phrase\third phrase\

>>> s.split('\\')
['', 'first phrase', 'second phrase', 'third phrase', '']

>>> s.split('\\')[1]
'first phrase'
```

The trick is to make sure the backslash is escaped by a backslash.
That's why it turns out to be `\\` that you are searching for or splitting on.

Comment: Not a direct answer to the OP's question, but it is a more Pythonic way to do what he's trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have an '\' as the last character of a string, even if it's a raw string - it needs to be written `'\\'` - in fact, if you look at your question, you'll see the highlighting go somewhat wonky - try changing it as suggested and it may well correct itself...